# Why doesnt the image load?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

for some reason the mario image wont load in the game
the forest.png is the background if you were to run
and the mario.png is the character
I have done some tests but no matter what it keeps not loading
this is also the game from the Tech With Tim tutorial I followed it line by line
yet it still doesn't work
(No errors it just doesnt load the character)

```
import pygame
import os, sys
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))


pygame.display.set_caption("the game!!!")
APP_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))

#background_image = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\NONAME\Desktop\Coding\Games\Learning\forest.png").convert()
background_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(APP_FOLDER, 'forest.png')).convert()

#mario = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\NO NAME\Desktop\Coding\Games\Learning\mario.png").convert()
R_mario = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(APP_FOLDER, 'mario.png')).convert()
L_mario = pygame.transform.flip(R_mario, True, False)


screenWidth = 500
x = 50
y = 425
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 10
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False    
right = True
walkcount = 0

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkcount

    win.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
    
    pygame.display.update()

    if left == True:
        win.blit(L_mario, (x, y))
        print("work left")
    elif right == True:
        win.blit(R_mario, (x, y))
        print("work right")


#mainloop
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        Left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_a] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        right = True
        left = False
    else:
        right = False
        left = False

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < screenWidth - width - vel:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < screenWidth - width - vel:
        x += vel

    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    redrawGameWindow()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: as I said there is no error message and i used the same thing for the background which worked fine

Comment: no  the character doesnt load

Comment: I can provide A image if you need

Comment: Does the image load when you uncomment the line with the full path and comment out the other one? And are you absolutely sure the image is there?

Comment: No sadly it doesnt

Comment: so how where I to solve this Rabbid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `blit` the character before updating the display:

```py
def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkcount

    win.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
    
    if left == True:
        win.blit(L_mario, (x, y))
        print("work left")
    elif right == True:
        win.blit(R_mario, (x, y))
        print("work right")

    pygame.display.update()
```

Note, however, if `right == False` and `left == False`, nothing is drawn at all.